# Looking for a service to display 2 factor auth codes online, rather than on my phone

Tags: security, google-apps, saas, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I am using my phone as 2 factor authentication.

I have some backup codes written down but in general - it would be a hassle to restore my credentials if my phone is lost.

I'm looking for 2 factor authentication online - a service let's call them `2FA-online` that offers a personalised URLs *(either password protected or not)* so that when authentication code is needed - I visit the URL without relying on the phone.

A potential attacker would not know whether I use phone or `2FA-online` so it appears safe to me - for the attacker any page would look as display of random, constantly changing numbers.

https://github.com/google/google-authenticator

> The pluggable authentication module (PAM) is in a separate project.

I'm able to see `C` code and because it was written and maintained by Google guys it presents relatively high standard of coding.

[image]

I'm hoping that someone has already incorporated this code into their product!

PS. For similar reasons outlined above - not using encryption - too worried about securely storing private key...

**EDIT / UPDATE:** Me doing backups, wondering why I cannot simply extract the seed from Google Authenticator app: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172428/what-are-the-security-consequences-of-allowing-2fa-app-google-authenticator-to

Comment: Alternative: Using a 2FA app (e.g. [AuthenticatorPlus](https://www.authenticatorplus.com/)) that has backup capabilites built-in.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to write something like this.

Whether it's secure enough? It depends on how secure your `2fa-online` web service is.

Here is a Python snippet using module [oath](https://pypi.org/project/oath/) which reads the base32-encoded shared secrets from the file given at first commmand-line argument and outputs a TOTP value with 6 digits:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Generate TOTP value based on key read from file
"""

import sys, base64, hashlib, binascii

import oath

secret = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read().strip()

print oath.totp(
    binascii.hexlify(base64.b32decode(secret)),
    format='dec6',
    period=30,
    t=None,
    hash=hashlib.sha1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Authy: https://authy.com/

It allows me to install app on my phone / laptop, therefore removing single point of failure of losing phone and not having 2FA seeds backed up.

Single point of failure of losing phone, someone putting SIM into a new device resetting my Gmail *(now they have Gmail and phone)* remains.

[image]